# Feathers JS MongoDB Service: Dynamic Collection Names

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, feathersjs, feathers-service

## Goal

I'm attempting to build a multi-tenant application with Feathers JS. On login, the tenant ID will be included in the request. From then on, the tenant ID will be gotten from the `user` field with the request parameters. Every user has this `tenantId` field.

In MongoDB, I have one unique collection of every data type per tenant. The collection names look like `tenantId.documents` and `tenantId.users`

## Problem

The service generated via the `feathers generate service` CLI command looks like so:

```
export class Documents extends Service {
  //eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  constructor(options: Partial<MongoDBServiceOptions>, app: Application) {
    super(options);

    const client: Promise<Db> = app.get('mongoClient');

    client.then(db => {
      this.Model = db.collection('documents');
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, the generated `Service`s seem to need their collection name ("documents" in this case) during instantiation. Normally, this makes sense since it saves time `await`ing a call to `app.get("mongoClient")`

However, since I need to dynamically change which collection I read from based on the User's `tenantId`, this won't work for me.

I implemented something like the following:

```
export class Documents extends Service {
  client: Promise<Db>
  //eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  constructor(options: Partial<MongoDBServiceOptions>, app: Application) {
    super(options);

    this.client = app.get("mongoClient");
  }

  async create(data: IDocumentData, params: Params) {
    const db: Db = await this.client;
    this.Model = db.collection(`${params.user!!.organizationId}.documents`);
    return super.create(data, params);
  }
}
```

The problems are these:

1. I need to `await this.client` every request, even when the promise will probably already be fulfilled by the time a user actually makes a request to this service
2. I have to implement every method of the parent `Service` even though I barely need to add any real functionality.

## Question

What is the most feathers-y way to solve this problem?

- I don't want to override every method that I need in every service
- I don't see a way to handle this with middleware or hooks.
- I also don't think it's necessary to create one service instance per tenant in my application. It seems wasteful since I don't need to make any additional external requests based on the tenant ID, I just need to change the collection

Is there a good, pretty way to do this in Feathers?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the helpful Feather community Slack channel, I think I came across a halfway-decent solution to this specific issue. It doesn't address all of my concerns, but at least it de-clutters my code.

First, I should create a new class that extends the built in `Service` class that implements the feature that I want. It could look something like this:

```
class DynamicMongoService extends Service {
  client: Promise<Db>;
  collectionName: string;

  constructor(
    options: Partial<MongoDBServiceOptions>,
    app: Application,
    collectionName: string
  ) {
    super(options);

    this.client = app.get("mongoClient");
    this.collectionName = collectionName;
  }

  async getCollection(params: Params) {
    const db: Db = await this.client;
    this.Model = db.collection(
      `${params!!.user!!.organizationId}.${this.collectionName}`
    );
  }

  async find(params?: Params) {
    await this.getCollection(params!!);
    return super.create(params!!);
  }

  async get(id: Id, params?: Params) {
    await this.getCollection(params!!);
    return super.get(id, params);
  }

  async create(data: Partial<any> | Array<Partial<any>>, params?: Params) {
    await this.getCollection(params!!);
    return super.create(data, params);
  }

  async update(id: NullableId, data: any, params?: Params) {
    await this.getCollection(params!!);
    return super.update(id!!, data, params);
  }

  async patch(id: NullableId, data: Partial<any>, params?: Params) {
    await this.getCollection(params!!);
    return super.patch(id!!, data, params);
  }

  async remove(id: NullableId, params?: Params) {
    await this.getCollection(params!!);
    return super.patch(id!!, params!!);
  }
}
```

The key elements are thus:

1. Pass collection name in the constructor
2. Get the collection name before each method

An implementation of this service would look like this:

```
export class Documents extends DynamicMongoService {
  constructor(options: Partial<MongoDBServiceOptions>, app: Application) {
    super(options, app, "documents");
  }
}
```

Not the best, but easy enough!